# Is body-data allowed after URL in wget?

Tags: command-line, wget, command-line-arguments

I just realized, due to an error on my part, that though [wget manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Invoking-1) only mentions URL at the end, I am able to specify body-data option *after* the URL. This is quite convenient, but I am wondering if this is behavior as designed.

```
$ wget --method=PUT -O -  http://httpbin.org/put --body-data='abcdefg'
--2019-03-27 10:52:30--  http://httpbin.org/put
Resolving httpbin.org (httpbin.org)... 3.85.154.144, 52.71.234.219
Connecting to httpbin.org (httpbin.org)|3.85.154.144|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 415 [application/json]
Saving to: ‘STDOUT’

-                              0%[                                               ]       0  --.-KB/s               {
  "args": {}, 
  "data": "", 
  "files": {}, 
  "form": {
    "abcdefg": ""
  }, 
  "headers": {
    "Accept": "*/*", 
    "Accept-Encoding": "identity", 
    "Content-Length": "7", 
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", 
    "Host": "httpbin.org", 
    "User-Agent": "Wget/1.19.1 (cygwin)"
  }, 
  "json": null, 
  "origin": "50.203.83.51, 50.203.83.51", 
  "url": "https://httpbin.org/put"
}
-                            100%[==============================================>]     415 --.-KB/s    in 0s      

2019-03-27 10:52:30 (4.53 MB/s) - written to stdout [415/415]
```

Comment: Arguments are often accepted in any order (as you have found here)... though that isn't true across the board for all applications... it's a good idea to check that what's happening is what you expect.

Comment: @Attie you are correct; *named* arguments are almost always unordered accept where order is significant. Unnamed arguments usually have to follow strict order as it may cause ambiguity. 

It is for this reason that I am looking for confirmation that this is as intended and not something that works perchance.

For comparison `curl` has a named parameter `--url/-u` to allow specifying URL anywhere on command line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is supported behaviour. For the Wget command line, you can put the URLs anywhere.

EDIT: From `info wget`, Section 2.2, Option Syntax:

> Since Wget uses GNU getopt to process command-line arguments, every
>   option has a long form along with the short one.  Long options are
>   more convenient to remember, but take time to type.  You may freely
>   mix different option styles, or specify options after the command-line
>   arguments.  Thus you may write:
>
> ```
>  wget -r --tries=10 http://fly.srk.fer.hr/ -o log
> ```

Comment: Thanks darnir. Is this documented somewhere?

Comment: Yes it is, in `info wget`. I added the text to my answer.

Comment: Thank you! It is in Section 2.2 of official wget manual at gnu.org that I linked to as well.